# Setting expiration for external Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pagespeed

I checked my site's speed using Google Page Speed, it suggest me to set expiration for java script files that are hosted somewhere. I set expiration for all files in my server but I don't know how I could add expire headers to scripts not on my server.
Here is a screenshot of that

[image: expiration for all files]

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The only way would be to serve those files from your own server.